# Integrate Android Eclipse project with Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-plus

I am new to unity.. I have implemented Google+ Service and its working perfectly in my android project.. I have taken reference from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share

But now i want to access this sharing functionalty from my unity project..

I do not know the steps which i need to perform to integrate this android project with my unity project..

For that i have reffered http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

But i am not getting clear idea from this document..

If anyone is having idea about this , then please guide me..

Thanks in advance for your support and help..

Comment: Please guys,, if you have any idea then let me know.. I am too confused about calling android class function from my unity javascript/c# script ??

Comment: The second link you've provided looks like the authoritative reference that describes what you want to do.  What don't you understand from that link?  I've never done any of this, but [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) seems to break up the process into small, easy to follow steps.  I doubt any of us can describe the process any better than the documentation written by the people at Unity.

Comment: I have created library of my project and then i have kept in plugins/android folder in unity editor.. Now what will be the next step?

Comment: To quote from your link: "_Once built, the shared library should be copied to the Assets->Plugins->Android folder. Unity will then find it by name when you define a function like the following in [a] C# script:_ `[DllImport ("PluginName")] private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();`" That seems preetty straightforward, no?

Comment: Also.... [This question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/258544/using-android-jar-library-smaad-sdk-with-unity.html) from [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) looks pretty relevant.  I think you'll find [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) to be more helpful than this site for most things directly related to Unity.

Comment: Here's a [detailed tutorial](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/unity-3d-integrating-smaad-sdk-more-games-android-activity-in-a-unity-android-game/) as well...

Comment: have posted this question on Unity Answer.. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/521444/integrate-android-eclipse-project-in-unity3d.html  But i get no response.

Answer (score 0):

use AndroidJNI and AndroidJNIHelper. it provides android java reflection.